# Currency conversion in online shopping website

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

In online shopping website that I have. How can I change currency back and forth from different currency rates based on user's selection preference or choice?

For example:

Suppose I have an user from UK so all items price must be converted in to Pound (£) when displayed. If that user want to see the item price in Rupee  and if the user is from INDIA so it will need to be automatically changed into Rupee,

Anybody can explain?

Answer (score 0):

I think we first need to setup localizations. Then what you should do is detect when the user logins or press a country and change the price rate. Accordingly you will have to do the following once the change of the user is noticed.

1. You need to have a way to keep the excange rate for Dollar , Pound and Ruppee in database or some sort of way.(Flags need to be turned on at this stage)
2. When that localization is activated you always recompute price based on the Flag let say if is USA flag is on. Then do the math and return your Items to the user and same as to other countries you want .

   `Itemprice * exchageRate` = `the actual price of the country rate`

Alloha .